# Is a super high odds ratio unusable?

Tags: logistic, odds-ratio

So I've been working on a logistic regression model, and all has been going well for the most part. However, I just started analyzing the results and trends of the model, and one particular odds ratio is giving me trouble. The odds ratios for the model (with four independent variables) are 0.9999999628643, 1.00000072117459, 0.0393990796298753, and 23974346.5342214.

Now this is obviously a huge problem. Most of them are fine, but then there's that one odds ratio in the twenty millions. While a larger odds ratio makes sense, as that's the variable that's probably going to have the largest impact on the output, I didn't anticipate having something that high. Is this unusable? Did I do something wrong? Thanks for any help you can offer!

**Edit**

The CI for the odds ratios are [0.999998601016136, 1.00000132471432], [0.999997388410105, 1.00000405395019], [1.02226897236851E-06, 1518.4726501918], and [0.810502926670688, 709151408131148].

Comment: The point estimates of ORs are not good. Always provide at least 95% Confidence Intervals - they also have drawbacks, but they are obviously better than point estimates.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed my question to include the CIs.

Comment: I think you already see that all of your CIs are including 1, no matter how huge the actual point estimate is. "Is this unusable?" - kind of, you may say that "there is no statistically significant difference in ORs" (you should think about the correct formulation of the conclusion, I provided a rough idea)

Comment: Huh. So basically, those CIs mean that none of the four inputs have a statistically significant effect on the output?

Comment: It's quite likely that the independent variables are collinear. Have you checked?

Comment: Agree with @PeterFlom-ReinstateMonica . As far as I know, this approach is more stable against multicollinearity: http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/36-classification-methods-essentials/149-penalized-logistic-regression-essentials-in-r-ridge-lasso-and-elastic-net/ - try glmnet (or just ridge approach).

Comment: So I check my VIFs, and they're all around 1.5. While this suggests some correlation, I don't think that's enough to be concerned about? Am I checked for mutlicollinearity the wrong way?

Comment: @JamesConnor I think it is correct. Try glmnet - if it will not work, then well, there are no meaningful predictors in your sample... (follow the tutorial and perform a cross-validation too)

Comment: OK, so I'm not using R for my model, but I managed to figure out how to use glmnet. The outputted coefficients show only V4 with a value (all the others are dots) Correct me if I'm interpreting this wrong, but does that mean that the other three exposures don't cause a statistically significant difference?

Comment: This is probably complete or quasi-complete separation, as in the duplicate. If you think that is not the case, report back!